# Finding Lag Polynomial Roots = Cayley-Hamilton?

Tags: time-series, linear-algebra

In my time series class we defined the lag polynomial by $\phi(L) = \sum_{i=0}^N\phi_i L^i$. It is well known that this polynomial can be factored as by $\prod_{i=0}^N(I - \lambda_i L)$ (note that $I$ denotes the "identity operator"). But then is the claim that we could "replace" $I$ by $1$ and $L$ by some some scalar $z$ and we look for the values $z_i$, $i=0,\dots, N$, such that $\prod_{i=0}^N(1 - \lambda_iz)$ is equal to zero.

I don't understand what "replace" means in context, or, in other words, why does it make sense to replace the operator by a scalar? This reminds me of the Caley-Hamilton theorem, where a scalar is "replaced" by a linear operator. Is this what is used to justify the above statement?

> **Cayley-Hamilton.** Suppose that $T$ is a linear operator on a vector space $V$. Then $\chi_T(T) = \mathsf{null}$.

Here $V = \mathbb R$ (usually), $T = L$, $\chi_L(\lambda) = \prod_{i=0}^N(I - \lambda L)$, $\mathsf{null} = 0\ (\in\mathbb R)$. Correct? (assuming that there are $N$ distinct eigenvalues)

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial can have matrix or operator inputs. let $p(x) = x^2 + 4x + 4 = (x+2)^2$. If $p(x)=0$ and if $\textbf{A}$ is a square matrix of full rank we have,

$p(\textbf{A}) = (\textbf{A}+2)^2 = (\textbf{A}+2)(\textbf{A}+2) = 0$

what is wrong with. the above? We need to 'replace' $2$ with $2\times\textbf{I}$

Now pick any column $c_j$ from $(\textbf{A}+2\textbf{I})$. We have,

($\textbf{A}+2\textbf{I})c_j = 0 \quad \implies \textbf{A}c_j = -2c_j$

So $c_j$ is an eigenvector of $\textbf{A}$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda = -2$. $c_j$ is obviously in the nullspace of $\textbf{A}$. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, every univariate polynomial of degree $n$ can be decomposed into $n$ monic polynomial terms. By [range-null-space decomposition](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/range-null-space-decomposition), because the null-space of a matrix of rank $n$ stabilizes (or stops growing) at [at most] $n$ powers of $\textbf{A}$ (e.g.$\textbf{A}^n$), we expect at most $n$ distinct eigenvalues (roots of $p(\textbf{A}) = 0$).  Ergo, the polynomial $\prod_i^n(\textbf{A}-\lambda_i\textbf{I}) = 0$ satisfies the characteristic equation.

In time-series analysis it is often the case that we need to divide by the eigenvalues so as to attain terms of the form $(1-\lambda_i^{-1}\textbf{B})$ where $\textbf{B}$ is the backshift operator. See section 3.6 of 'Time Series: Theory and Methods' by Brockwell and Davis.